# 2D array passing in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

**How can I create an array so that I can pass it as a pointer to this function?**

```
void SomeFunction(double *a, double *b, double *c);
```

**I made my 2d arrays like so (but I have errors):**

```
static double matrix_a [MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];
static double matrix_b [MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];
static double matrix_c [MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];

for (i=0;i<MATRIX_DIM;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<MATRIX_DIM;j++) {
        // initializing matrices here
    }
}
```

*Now I make pointers to the arrays:*

```
double *a = &matrix_a;
double *b = &matrix_b;
double *c = &matrix_c;
```

*And then call the function:*

```
SomeFunction(a, b, c);
```

However I get the following error:

```
cannons.c: In function ‘main’:
cannons.c:29:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type      [enabled by default]
double *a = &matrix_a;
              ^
cannons.c:30:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
double *b = &matrix_b;
              ^
cannons.c:31:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
double *c = &matrix_c;
              ^
```

Why ?

Comment: Is it because the args you are passing aren't pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double *` means "pointer to a single double". However you have an array whose elements are arrays of double.  So you in fact want a pointer to an array of double:

```
double (*a)[MATRIX_DIM] = &matrix_a[0];   // or matrix_a
```

when you access it as `a[1][2] = 5.0;`. Alternatively you could point to the entire array at once:

```
double (*x)[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM] = &matrix_a;
```

but then you need an extra level of indirection to access it: `(*x)[1][2] = 5.0;`

You will need to use the same declaration in the parameter list too.

Comment: how can i make the arrays so they fit what is expected by the function argument list?  i don't understand how the function works so I cannot change the type, but i need to pass 2d arrays into it

Comment: @abc you can use `(double *)&matrix_a`. This will present the function with a 1-D array view in row-major order